# How do images work in opencl kernel?

Tags: c++, c, opencl, gpgpu

I'm trying to find ways to copy multidimensional arrays from host to device in opencl and thought an approach was to use an image... which can be 1, 2, or 3 dimensional objects. However I'm confused because when reading a pixle from an array, they are using vector datatypes. Normally I would think double pointer, but it doesn't sound like that is what is meant by vector datatypes. Anyway here are my questions:

1) What is actually meant to vector datatype, why wouldn't we just specify 2 or 3 indices when denoting pixel coordinates? It looks like a single value such as float2 is being used to denote coordinates, but that makes no sense to me. I'm looking at the function read_imageui and read_image.

2) Can the input image just be a subset of the entire image and sampler be the subset of the input image? I don't understand how the coordinates are actually specified here either since read_image() only seams to take a single value for input and a single value for sampler.

3) If doing linear algebra, should I just bite the bullet and translate 1-D array data from the buffer into multi-dim arrays in opencl?

4) I'm still interested in images, so even if what I want to do is not best for images, could you still explain questions 1 and 2?

Thanks!

**EDIT**
I wanted to refine my question and ask, in the following khronos documentation they define...

```
 int4 read_imagei (
    image2d_t image,
    sampler_t sampler,
    int2 coord)
```

But nowhere can I find what image2d_t's definition or structure is supposed to be. The samething for sampler_t and int2 coord. They seem like structs to me or pointers to structs since opencl is supposed to be based on ansi c, but what are the fields of these structs or how do I note the coord with what looks like a scala?! I've seen the notation (int2)(x,y), but that's not ansi c, that looks like scala, haha. Things seem conflicting to me. Thanks again!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In general you can read from images in three different ways:

1. direct pixel access, no sampling
2. sampling, normalized coordinates
3. sampling, integer coordinates

The first one is what you want, that is, you pass integer pixel coordinates like (10, 43) and it will return the contents of the image at that point, with no filtering whatsoever, as if it were a memory buffer. You can use the `read_image*()` family of functions which take no `sampler_t` param.

The second one is what most people want from images, you specify normalized image coords between 0 and 1, and the return value is the interpolated image color at the specified point (so if your coordinates specify a point in between pixels, the color is interpolated based on surrounding pixel colors). The interpolation, and the way out-of-bounds coordinates are handled, are defined by the configuration of the `sampler_t` parameter you pass to the function.

The third one is the same as the second one, except the texture coordinates are not normalized, and the sampler needs to be configured accordingly. In some sense the third way is closer to the first, and the only additional feature it provides is the ability to handle out-of-bounds pixel coordinates (for instance, by wrapping or clamping them) instead of you doing it manually.

Finally, the different versions of each function, e.g. `read_imagef`, `read_imagei`, `read_imageui` are to be used depending on the pixel format of your image. If it contains floats (in each channel), use `read_imagef`, if it contains signed integers (in each channel), use `read_imagei`, etc...

Writing to an image on the other hand is straightforward, there are `write_image{f,i,ui}()` functions that take an image object, integer pixel coordinates and a pixel color, all very easy.

Note that you **cannot read and write to the same image in the same kernel**! (I don't know if recent OpenCL versions have changed that). In general I would recommend using a buffer if you are not going to be using images as actual images (i.e. input textures that you sample or output textures that you write to only once at the end of your kernel).

---

About the `image2d_t`, `sampler_t` types, they are OpenCL "pseudo-objects" that you can pass into a kernel from C (they are reserved types). You send your image or your sampler from the C side into clSetKernelArg, and the kernel gets back a sampler_t or an image2d_t in the kernel's parameter list (just like you pass in a buffer object and it gets a pointer). The objects themselves cannot be meaningfully manipulated inside the kernel, they are just handles that you can send into the read_image/write_image functions, along with a few others.

---

As for the "actual" low-level difference between images and buffers, GPU's often have specially reserved texture memory that is highly optimized for "read often, write once" access patterns, with special texture sampling hardware and texture caches to optimize scatter reads, mipmaps, etc..

On the CPU there is probably no underlying difference between an image and a buffer, and your runtime likely implements both as memory arrays while enforcing image semantics.

Comment: Nice answer, Thomas. To point out, why images use float value parameters. CLImages have their basis in texture handling on the GPU for screen rendering. As objects do have rapidly changing space coordinates (in games etc.), their pasted textures are based on a [0.0,1.0[  range interval. An so OpenCL does.

Comment: Hmm, I guess the brunt of the confusion comes from Khronos definition of coordinates:

 int4 read_imagei (  image2d_t image,
   sampler_t sampler,
   float2 coord)

To me image2d_t and sampler_t seem like either structs or pointers to structs, which I can get because its is ansi c based which opencl is supposed to adhere to, but float2 coord confuses me because it doesn't say anywhere in the docs how I'm supposed to set the coordinates. My guess is:

coo.x = 5; coo.y = 6;

But I don't see it anywhere in the docs. I wish that the data struct for image2d_t and sampler_t where explained.

Comment: @Mr.Student They are OpenCL "pseudo-objects" that you can pass into a kernel from C. You send your image or your sampler from the C side into clSetKernelArg, and the kernel gets back a sampler_t or an image2d_t in the kernel's parameter list (just like you pass in a buffer object and it gets a pointer). The objects themselves cannot be meaningfully manipulated inside the kernel, they are just handles that you can send into the read_image/write_image functions.

Comment: @Thomas: Ok, thanks that's exactly what I didn't understand! Do you have any reference or tutorials that explains this in greater detail? Anyway, answer accepted, thanks again!

Comment: @Mr.Student I think the best reference really is the OpenCL standard (along with the OpenCL C standard). It's a bit of a dreary read but it covers everything and is quite searchable. Once you are familiar with the API, the CL quick reference card is amazingly handy: https://www.khronos.org/files/opencl-1-2-quick-reference-card.pdf

Comment: Actually this is also a good source too: http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1732873&seqNum=3